# MATLAB multidimensional Filter Array

Tags: matlab, filtering

I just designed an IIR filter with the fdatool in MATLAB and exported the coefficients to a header file. I copied the arrays over to MATLAB and now I trying to plot the frequency response. However for some reason the arrays are multidimensional and I'm not sure how to make MATLAB handle that.

This is what my filter coefficients look like:

```
num = [
    [0.7167852126947,0,0],
    [1,-1.919646855375,1],
    [0.4393545211166,0,0],
    [1,-1.603319802493,1],
    [0.03175470360035,0,0],
    [1,-1.942960840584,1],
    [1,0,0]
];

den = [
  [1,0,0],
  [1,-1.904445073337,0.9382561062801],
  [1,0,0],
  [1,-1.837789625289,0.8507293334097],
  [1,0,0],
  [1,-1.942552416592,0.9865719866549],
  [1,0,0]
];
```

If they were single dimensional I could just pass them to the **freqz** function in MATLAB like so:

```
freqz(num,den);
```

But this gives me an error with the above arrays.

What's the best way to plot the frequency response of the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the format of `num` and `den` I have the following presumption:

MATLAB's `fdatool` by default creates second-order-sections for IIR filters and returns a matrix of second-order-sections (they call it SOS Matrix). The SOS form looks like this:

[image: SOS form]

while the SOS matrix returned by MATLAB has the following format:

[image: sos matrix]

Now, your `num` looks exactly like the part of the matrix containing all `b`'s, while `den` contains the ones (which are actually `a_0`'s) and the `a`'s.

Most MATLAB functions (includeing the `freqz` function) can handle `sos`-matrices, so it would be advisable to create the sos matrix and call the function by:

```
sos = [num,den];
freqz(sos);
```

It appears this is not supported in older versions of MATLAB. In that case you'll have to convert it to the `tf` (transfer function) format first:

```
[b,a] = sos2tf(sos);
freqz(b,a);
```

Comment: So that got rid of the errors but it still looks nothing like the filter preview in fdatool. I used the following code:
freqz(num,den,1:1:10000,48000)
This is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/CZwBaOh.png

Comment: Just use the `num` and `den` you have in your question and the code i posted (no other changes). Then you will get the same as the preview in the `fdatool`

Comment: On my computer (MATLAB R2015a) it produces the same output as `fdatool` in your case. Can you `clear all` and copy paste the `num` and `den` + the code provided into MATLAB and see what happens? What MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: So If I separate the arrays into separate lines like in my question I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/IyADJUP.png but if I but them all on the same line I get this: http://i.imgur.com/47vA4mn.png
I'm using MATLAB 2012b

Comment: Hm it seems to me that this feature doesn't exist yet in MATLAB 2012b. Then this should do the job: `[b,a] = sos2tf(sos); freqz(b,a)` Does that work?

Comment: No. I played around with that earlier but I kept getting: "Error using sos2tf. SOS matrix must have six columns."

Comment: But it should have six columns (and has on my pc). Can you verify it has the format as the matrix in my answer?

Comment: Oops. My bad. Typo on my part. :) Thanks for your help! It looks great now.

Comment: Perfect :) I added this to the answer so it is complete.